# get outer div by id, then get inner div by class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

First I want to get the outer div by id, then the inner div by class (dynamically added by jquery mobile ui-collapsible content) and finally append a child text node to it.

```
<div id="aab" data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
     <h3>Heading</h3>
     <div class="ui-collapsible-content">
         <div id="coll">
             Collapsible Content
         </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <p><button onclick='func()'>Button</button></p>    

   <script>
        function func() {
            var section = $("#aab > .ui-collapsible-content"); 
            section.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello world!"));
        }
    </script>
```

I also tried things out with document.getElementById but somehow it doesn't work.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any element with class `ui-collapsible-content`. Btw, do you know that `>` means **direct** child?

Comment: @zerkms: the div "coll" will be automatically wrapped in a div with the class ui-collapsible-content. I also tried alert($("#aab > .ui-collapsible-content").text()); and I got Collapsible Content as an alert so it works for the text child but I want the wrapped div with the class ui-collapsible-content which will be automatically added and wrap the div id="coll".

Comment: @user1054134: so please show html as if it was wrapped so that we don't need to make any assumptions

Comment: added the collapsible content div

Comment: now define what "doesn't work" in your question mean? The selector is good

Comment: I think the document.createTextNode doesn't work because in the editor I get no suggestions when I type "document.cre"  I only get createPopup and not "createTextNode". I write the script in the html and not in an extra js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have use jquery for selection so you should use it for adding child

```
function func() {
  var section = $("#aab > .ui-collapsible-content"); 
  section.append("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! what is "document.appendChild" or document.createTextNode notation? Is that not javascript?

Comment: @user1054134: where did you get them?

Comment: It's pure javascript but you can only call appendChild when you select an element with docuemtn.getElementById() ... But in this case  you have jQuery already, easier to write than pure js. You can still use pure code like this section.get(0).appendChild ...

Comment: Thanks for that comment! but I don't even get that to work if all the other stuff is commented out: var b = document.getElementById("#coll").text();
                alert(b); But this jquery stuff works: var b = $("#coll").text();
                alert(b); Maybe I have to load that in the window.onload function..

Comment: noooo the # is only use for jsuery id selection. pure js doesnot have that b = document.getElementById("coll") will work

Comment: very nice, thanks! what is $("#aab > .ui-collapsible-content") and $("#aab > div") in javascript code and not in jquery? i need it for a mobile app where a lot of dynamic content will be generated (via xml web service) and i think it will be better to search for elements and generate elements via javascript for performance reasons..